# partition key size in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.0

How do I extract/calculate the partition key size:
nodetool cfhistograms, reports Max Partition key associated with Cell count, but doesn't say which anything about large key(s).

is there a way to extract the largest partition key or atleast get a listing of all partition keys + size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to calculate partition key size: https://shermandigital.com/blog/calculate-the-size-of-a-cassandra-table/

> Cassandra stores at least 15 bytes worth of metadata for each column. Counter columns require an additional eight bytes of overhead as do expiring columns (columns with the time-to-live value set). In addition to metadata, we need space for the name of each column and the value stored within it

And then

> Every partition key requires 23 bytes of metadata

So you calculate the size of columns (including partition key columns) with:

```
column_size = column_metadata + column_name_value + column_value
```